# Use dependencies in R packages through library() / Description file

Tags: r, r-package

I'm writing an R package that has several dependencies of other packages, some of them are available in CRAN and other ones are homemade.

According to the help, `library("my_package")` will load the namespace of the package once I have previously installed it, i.e,  `install.package("my_package")`.

Nevertheless, once I have installed the package I am able to use all the functions of the installed but not loaded package through `my_package::my_function()`, so if my package has dependencies, beside adding those into `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports:
    dplyr,
    my_package2,
    ggvis,
```

in the root of the package folder.
Do I have to load the dependencies of the new package through `library()` or the final user will see an error if he has not installed on his computer as the required packages are specified in the *Imports* section?

Comment: You should never use `library` inside a package. The reason is, that your package code is executed once in the building process. So you should stick to the dependency fields in the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: For further details just check the passage on dependencies in Hadley Wickham: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter A more important reason for not using `library` is, I feel, that it pollutes the `search()` of the package’s user. Libraries have no business changing the global state of the session (unfortunately R makes this occasionally hard, and many packages behave badly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the user does not have to load the packages that are used by functions in `my_package`.

The fact that you have listed a package under `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file means that during the installation of `my_package`, R will check that this package is available on your system. This means then that functions in `my_package` can use functions from these packages using the `::` notation, as you suggested.

Using the `::` notation is the recommended way to refer to functions from other packages, but there are also other options:

- In order to make all the functions from, say, `dplyr` accessable without `::` in `my_package`, you could add `import(dplyr)` to the `NAMESPACE` file. This is convenient, if you use many functions from a package.
- If you intend to use only, say, the function `select` from `dplyr`, you could add `importFrom(select, dplyr)` to the `NAMESPACE` file.
- You could also add the package to the `DESCRIPTION` file under `Depends:`. This would mean that the package is loaded to the global environment when you use `library(my_package)`. This is almost never a good solution.

The general idea of dependencies is R is that `my_package` will have "it's own version" of the packages it depends on loaded. Therefore, you can always be sure that you will, e.g., use the function `select()` from the `dplyr` package, as you intended to do. The exception is the use of `Depends:` which bypasses this system. In this case, `my_package` will look for functions in the global environment and if somebody should have defined some function called `select()` in the global environment, `my_package` will use this function and you will get unexpected results.

**Example 1:**

`DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports:
    dpylr
```

some function from `my_package`:

```
my_fun <- function(...) {
    dplyr::mutate(...) %>%
    dplyr::select(1:3)
}
```

**Example 2:**

`DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports:
    dpylr
```

`NAMESPACE` file:

```
import(dplyr)
```

some function from `my_package`:

```
my_fun <- function(...) {
    mutate(...) %>%
    select(1:3)
}
```

**Example 3:**

`DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Imports:
    dpylr
```

`NAMESPACE` file:

```
importFrom(dplyr,select)
```

some function from `my_package`:

```
my_fun <- function(...) {
    dpylr::mutate(...) %>%
    select(1:3)
}
```

You find more detailed explanations of how to handle dependencies in R packages on the web. For instance the following are useful:

- [On the DESCRIPTION file](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)
- [On the NAMESPACE file](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)

Also, it is not necessary to write the `NAMESPACE` file by hand. You can let  `roxygen2` do that for you. Read the [documentation](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/) for more information.

Comment: I would amend “almost never” to “never” when it comes to using `Depends` … but I know that some people disagree with this. Nevertheless, consider that you are polluting the user’s global state, and potentially changing the semantics of other loaded packages.

Comment: I fully agree with you that `Depends` should never be used. But I have experienced cases where a package that I import somehow need another package to be loaded to the global environment and I have not managed to get around using `Depends`. So it seems that bad design in other packages might force one to use `Depends` as well. This is what I meant: it should not be used, but sometimes there is no other practical way.

Comment: The syntax is `importFrom(package, function)` and not `importFrom(select, dplyr)`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur You are right, of course. Thanks for the hint!